# Colisiones canvas

Tags: javascript, canvas

Tengo un método en el que quiero posar a Mario sobre un obstáculo y que camine, pero si no ha saltado se quede pegado a la izquierda del obstaculo, la que la m es Mario y o cada obstáculo iterado, en el `if` compruebo si la altura de Mario es diferente a la original por lo que esta saltando después si la altura de Mario es mayor al objeto  y la anchura de Mario mayor del obstáculo y la ultima es para ver si colisiona por la derecha ya habiendo saltado el obstáculo, en ese caso posiciono a Mario a la derecha si choca pero sobre el obstáculo si esta encima, pero no me va que me falta. Gracias.

```js
ObstacleCollection.prototype.checkCollitionObstacles = function(m){         
    this.obstaclesArray.forEach(function(o){
        if ((m.y !== m.y0) && (m.y + m.h) >= o.y && (m.x + m.w) > o.x && m.x <= (o.x + o.w)) {
            m.y = o.y - m.h;
            console.log('se sube al obstaculo');
        }
        if (m.y === m.y0 && m.x + m.w >= o.x && m.x + m.w < o.x + o.w){
             m.x = o.x - m.w;
             console.log('se coloca a la izquierda del obstaculo');
        }
        if (m.x > o.x + o.w && m.x <= o.x + o.w) {
            m.x = o.x + o.w;
            console.log('no se coloca a la derecha del obstaculo');
        }
        
    }); 
};
```

Comment: Hola francisco dwq, por favor edita tu pregunta para darle un título descriptivo y añadir algo más de information (explicar cómo no va el código compartido o si recibes algún error). Lee [ask] para más información.

Comment: no hay error, actualice el codigo, es un juego de super mario, el primer if me sube mario al obstaculo si esta saltando, el segundo me coloca a mario a izquierda de obstaculo si choca cuando no esta saltando, el ultimo no me deja a mario a la derecha del obstaculo si chioco por el otro lado